# storing k largest ints from set S in O(log k) time O(k) space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

i have an exam with a question as follows:

Let S be a dynamic set of integers. At the beginning, S is empty. Then, new integers
are added to it one by one, but never deleted. Let k be a fixed integer.

Describe an algorithm to
maintain the k largest integers in S. Your algorithm must use O(k) space at all times, no matter
how large |S| is (note that |S| increases continuously, but your space cannot).

Furthermore, it must
process every integer insertion in O(log k) time.

For example, suppose that k = 3, and that the sequence of integers inserted is 83, 21, 66, 5, 24,
76, 92, 32, 43... Your algorithm must be keeping {83, 66, 24} after the insertion of 24, {83, 66, 76}
after the insertion of 76, and {83, 76, 92} after the insertion of 43.

without S being sorted or structured im unsure how i would be able to complete this??

Comment: Isn't it just heap?

Comment: A min heap of size k.

Comment: how would it be possible to find the largest integer in S and then insert it in O(logk) though? the insertion into heap size K would be O(log k) alone wouldn't it?

Comment: @101ldaniels you don't store the set S at all, just the k largest elements of it. As new elements arrive, it is easy to decide if they should be kept or not.

Comment: ahhhh i see, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using min heap of size k. A min-heap is a complete binary tree in which the value in each internal node is lesser than or equal to the values in the children of that node. But all you have to do is just restrict the size of the heap and every time you get a new element just check if that element is greater than the root element if not check the other element that are already in the heap, if so the replace that element with the new element. As you have asked it requires O( k) space and insertion time is also O(log k). Hope it helps you.

Comment: No, the insertion time is O(log k).

Comment: There is a reason the comment above proposed a min-heap. Think again through your answer.

Comment: I am not able to find the difference.Can you please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: How long would it take with your structure to find out "if that element is greater than any of the elements that are already in the heap"? Can you do that in O(log k) time?

Comment: Yeah.It takes O(n log n) in the worst case.Thanks for finding it out.

Comment: Not quite, it is O(k) but still too much to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127090/discussion-between-anagh-hegde-and-henry).

Comment: You should edit your answer because, as of now, this is the accepted answer and it's wrong.